# Touchpad doesnt work before and after login,but usb mouse works

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, dell, synaptics

My dell laptops synaptic touchpad doesn't work after installing last update for Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell inspiron 15 laptop

but the Usb mouse works finely.

I tried all of the following commands and got exhausted.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```

and `xinput list` gives following output.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ Synaptics s3203                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎣ Virtual core keyboard      ..........
.............
```

it shows that the touchpad has been recognized. and

```
$ xinput list-props 12 | grep "Device Enabled"
Device Enabled (143):   1
```

it shows the device is enabled

and `apt list --installed` shows

```
xserver-xorg-input-mouse/bionic,now 1:1.9.2-1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic,now 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

it also gives good news.

**but**

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -I touchpad
```

returns a blank as not as expected (as mentioned in another article ([this article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-touchpad-not-working-linux/)))

but nothing works for me.

most important , I checked for hardware solutions also. there is no touchbad disable button or I haven't pressed any touchpad disabling key combination.

Comment: Possibly useful - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798  (see esp. last update)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my new laptop. I tried some of the things above, but what finally worked for me was the following:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tried all sayed here, continues not working. In the terminal return same things as Kavindu Ravishka.

Thanks for share possible useful link @guiverc

I'm done a research and read on comments in the link send by guiverc, has a response that say the next:

> Please stay at 4.15.0-70 kernel or apply the patches above in
>   maillist. The fix should be in next release.

By the way is waiting for the next release.

I downgraded kernel version 4.15.0-70 which is the penultimate of my current (4.15.0-72). It worked!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MK7Z19rMn8

Answer (score 0):

The solution still is in construction, according to this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798

Then, the better fix is downgrading and use the kernel version 4.15.0-70.